# How to include Uninstall MyProgram.exe in visual studio while creating package in c#

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-installer

I have developed a wpf application and created setup for that. I am using windows installer for creating setup package. Now I want to include uninstall MyProgram.exe in start menu after installing my package.
I am able to add the exe to run my program after installation. I want to include uninstall MyProgram.exe, ReadMe file, Help File in start menu.
Any suggestions plz help me regarding this.
Thanks in advance,
Ibrahim.

Answer (score 1):

When you create installation package, it is assigned unique id (Product Code, if i'm not forgetting). You can create a batch file with following line:

```
  @echo off
  start /b /l msiexec.exe /x {Product Code}
```

Now right click on file system tree (in files view of project) and include this batch file. Assign it a nice icon and create entry "Uninstall " to start menu folder for your application.

ps:- just type msiexec.exe in run or cmd window to get more options.
pps:- Product Code is available in properties of your setup project. Select Setup Project in solution tree and open properties tab.

Comment: I did the samething what you told but it went to command prompt and from there it is uninstalling. Is there any otherway for this without going to command prompt.

Comment: Sorry, Please use " start /B /l msiexec.exe /i {prod code}". This too shows command window but it is automatically closed, just a glimpse of it!

Comment: I did the samething. I am getting the command window. Instead of command window i want some window which is having unintall button.
Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

did you have a look at this post?
[How to add uninstall option in .NET Setup Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61691/how-to-add-uninstall-option-in-net-setup-project)

You can create an uninstall shortcut and then add this shortcut to your start menu. the post below explains how to add a shortcut to user's desktop, you can get the idea and apply the same things for the start menu.
[desktop shortcut icon not showing in web setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926232/desktop-shortcut-icon-not-showing-in-web-setup-project)