# How to include setup file in the same Setup Deployment?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, setup-deployment

I'm deploying application written in C# with .NET Framework 4.0 CP using Visual Studio 2010. I'd like to include uninstall option in the application folder. I've already tried creating shortcut to *msiexec.exe* system file but that didn't really worked for me, besides I've heard that on earlier OS (I'm on Win7) it might cause problems.

As I noticed one can uninstall program using the same setup that was used for installing it. So right now I'm somehow trying to include or create the setup file in the application folder. How exactly can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

already answered here:

http://sivanandareddyg.blogspot.com/2012/06/creating-uninstall-shortcut-for-your.html

[How to include Uninstall MyProgram.exe in visual studio while creating package in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994900/how-to-include-uninstall-myprogram-exe-in-visual-studio-while-creating-package-i)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/nipuntomar/making-a-uninstall-shortcut-with-visual-studio-setup-project/

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I don't want to create a shortcut to msiexec.exe as you're suggesting. I simply want to include the setup file I'm currently creating. To put it simply, when user installs the app using setup file and then looks into the application folder (folder with application data, binaries etc. usually located in "Program Files" folder) he sees there the setup file - the same setup he used to install the app in the first place.